# Dojo selector syntax - IE bug in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

We are using Dojo 1.4 (we hope to upgrade someday.)   I am trying to find the syntax to perform a dojo.query() using an iterated list of attributes rather than a matching selector.    I am looking for something like this:

```
dojo.query("[id=thisDivID, id=thatDivID]")
```

but I cannot get the syntax right.

I have HTML resembling the following example code:

```
<DIV id='someNameHere'>
    <SPAN id='dontSelectThis'></SPAN>
    <DIV id='thisDivID'> text and code here </DIV>
    <DIV id='thatDivID'> text and code here </DIV>
</DIV>
```

and I'm trying to select only the two inner DIVs using

```
dojo.query("[id$='DivID']")
```

It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but returns extra results in IE.   There is a "DOCTYPE" declaration for the page (I gather that is a common IE problem).

I have already looked through all the examples I can find on the dojo site and none seem to address this problem.

Comment: What version of IE? And Dojo?

Comment: Dojo 1.4, thanks for pointing out.   Question edited.   IE - we cannot get it to work in 7, 8 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this with IE8,9 and Dojo 1.8.3

http://jsfiddle.net/cswing/JNZXQ/

In addition to the versions, do you know the selector engine that you are using?

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/query.html

Maybe you could try this query

```
dojo.query("div[id$='DivID']")
```